# javascript fires on load not click

Tags: javascript

My goal:
Have an img in the defalt tab when the page loads. The user clicks on the img and it fades to revile the tab below.

My problem:
With in my html page I've placed a img tag. In the header there's a javascript that successfully fades the img when it's clicked. However when the img is placed with in the content section of "Tabs" area the fade fires when I load the page.  I'm sure there's a conflict between the two scripts. My fade script (on the html page) and the external javascript running the "Tabs".

A side note: I've done countless arrangements placing the img tag with in the html tag layout. As well working with the css.

thanks for any advice.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<title>page</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style13.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script src="Js/tabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="tabstyle.css" /><script>

$(document).click(function(){
   $("img").fadeOut('slow', function() {
       $("img").removeClass();
      });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="WRAPPER">

<img src="images/tvOff.jpg" width="760" height="523">

<p class="dropcontent">

<div id="cyclelinks"></div>
</p>

<p class="dropcontent">
<img src="images/tvOn.jpg" width="760" height="523">
</p>

<p class="dropcontent">
<img src="images/logo1.png" >
</p>

</div><!--WRAPPER CLOSE-->`enter code here`
<div class="tvBase"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You placed the `click` on the entire document, not just images. You also fade all images, not just the clicked one.

```
$("img").click(function(){
   $(this).fadeOut('slow', function() {
       $(this).removeClass();
   });
});
```

Comment: James, Thanks for your answer. It made me release the js handling the tabs need to go. So I put in new js to run the tabs and it works great. Here is part of the page. http://jsfiddle.net/othoap/6skqh/2/  Thanks to everyone at overFlow for all your time.